# Why doesn't .click work when $(document.ready(function() is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where this code is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      console.log('document ready');
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger : 'manual',
        placement : 'right'
      }).click(function(e) {

        console.log('click');
```

In my console i see 'document read', so it is loaded. But when i click on the data-toggle, it doesn't work. Only if i reload the whole page with F5, the datta-toggle works. Someone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle or plunkr please.

Comment: How do html looks like? any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Had my html page within an ui-view, this prevents the jquery .click to be loaded when entering the page, only after F5 reload it will load the .click event.

Now the page is loaded outside the ui-view and it works.